# Why I can see "box n" in my bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
%twoside yaz iki taraflı için
\usepackage[top=2.5 cm, bottom=2.5 cm, left=4 cm, right=2.5 cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[turkish,shorthands=:!]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{dnm.bib}
\addto\captionsturkish{\renewcommand\bibname{Kaynakça}}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
Latex is the best \cite{alman}.

But sometimes it's hard \cite{pdf_26}.

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, title=KAYNAKLAR]

\end{document}
```

Here's my WME when I compile it I saw "box and n." But if I delete  \setmainfont{Times New Roman} part the box is gone. The problem is I want Times New Roman but don't want to see an empty box in my pdf.

```
@inproceedings{pdf_26,
  title={Structure and parameters design of output LC filter in D-STATCOM},
  author={Wang, Cunping and Yin, Xianggen and Wen, Minghao and Liu, Jian and Xiong, Qing and Zhang, Bin},
  booktitle={Power System Technology (POWERCON), 2010 International Conference on},
  pages={1--6},
  year={2010},
  organization={IEEE}
}
@book{alman,
  title={Planning and installing photovoltaic systems: a guide for installers, architects and engineers},
  author={Sonnenenergie, Deutsche Gesellshaft Fur},
  year={2007},
  publisher={Earthscan}
}
```

Comment: `biblatex` has no support for Turkish, yet. As far as I can see, the problem is that the first letter of “in” is capitalized; according to Turkish rules, the uppercase variant is not “I”, but ”İ”, which seems to be the problem here. If I add `english` to the options for `babel` and `\selectlanguage{english}` before the bibliography, the output is correct.

Comment: `\MakeLowercase{I}` and `\MakeUppercase{i}` both fail in your document, that's why `biblatex` can't capitalise the the `in:` properly.